On restart, VS Code fails to ignore a directory listed in `.gitignore` containing a second repo
I am using Nanoc as a static site generator, managed with GIT.
Nanoc creates an "output" directory in the site’s main repo. This is explicitly excluded in the site's main .gitignore file with output/. Inside the "output" directory is another, separate GIT repo with a remote to the server, from which the newly-generated local files are pushed via SSH to a bare GIT repo on the remote server, where a post-receive hook there moves the files to the site root.
This local inner repo isn’t manually updated, as (it seems) some unfathomable "magic" adds changes and commits the updates (I can’t work out how and presume it must be a combination of the parent GIT repo and Nanoc—perhaps someone can explain?).
This works fine, and when Nanoc updates the "output" directory, nanoc deploy uses SSH to push changes in "output" to the server.
However, every time VSCode is relaunched, it starts tracking the "output" directory again, and I have to jump through a few hoops to prevent this once I start making changes. Why does VSCode do this?

Had you previously added output?

It’s possible that before I added .gitignore Nanoc generated the directory, but a very long time ago. Back then I also did git rm -r --cached output/, a command that now returns "fatal: pathspec 'output/' did not match any files"
